# Find Missing Number from a given arithmetic progression

Tags: algorithm

I came across this problem where you were given a number `N` as Input and then N numbers followed (where 3<=N<=2500). These `N` numbers were part of an Arithmetic Progression (of size `N+1`) from which one number was removed. So the task was to find that Missing number. For instance

```
5
1 3 5 9 11
```

The output is `7`

I came up with two methods, the 2nd one passing all the test cases but the first one failing in certain (hidden) cases.

First I will explain the second method

METHOD II

```
Let diff=(last_number-first_number)/N
 //Considering 0 based indexing
 for i=0 to (N-2)
    if( array[i+1] is not equal to (array[i]+diff))
          print (array[i]+diff)
          break
```

This method passed all the test cases. Now the first method which I implemented and which failed certain test cases was as follows

METHOD I

```
 //Considering 0 based indexing
 for i=1 to (N-2)
      if (2*array[i] is not equal to (array[i-1]+array[i+1])) then
              if( (array[i]-array[i-1])< (array[i+1]-array[i]))
                      print 2*array[i]-array[i-1]
              else 
                      print 2*array[i]-array[i+1]
              break
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with `METHOD I`?? Which cases am I missing.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be an exact duplicate of (or at least highly related to) [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19426660/1639625).

Comment: why do you use this condition:
if (2*array[i] is not equal to (array[i]+array[i+1]))

what if the array is 1 10 19, then it will not work.

Comment: @tobias_k.. Yeah..I guess we went to the same site..However I guess I have a different problem...

Comment: @Wasafa1...Ohh sorry that was a typo...and the minimum value of N=3. Making the edit

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact method you submitted? In your METHOD I the second case can only be used if the second element in the progression is missing (otherwise the missing number would already have been found for `i-1`). If you have a typo in that case, it would explain why it fails in specific cases.

Comment: This is a Sample Facebook Interview Programming Question. More Answers [HERE](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=4798365246160896)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method 1 does not work when the numbers are in decreasing order.

For 7 5 1 output should be 3 but the algorithm will give 9.

Method 2 works in this case because the difference is correctly calculated as negative and the algorithm proceeds accordingly.

Comment: I didn't get you, according to OP method 1 fails.

Comment: diff = (1 - 7) / 3 = -2. First iteration of cicle will be 5 == 7 + (-2), is a true and in second fails.

Comment: OP is calling 1st one as method 2 :)

Comment: Sorry, understand that author enumerate methods in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

Though not answer of your original question but if you need it a better solution with O(logN) complexity for the finding the missing number(if there is only one). Use binary search .

make following comparision for binary search

```
  if(a[mid] != mid*(difference)+a[0]) {

        missing_num = mid*(difference) + a[0];
        search lower half
  }

  else search higher half
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution in Ruby:

```
number_of_terms = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Get number of terms from STDIN

```
progression = gets.chomp.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
```

Get the string, remove any leading and trailing white space, split it at the spaces between the numbers and then convert each item into an integer.

```
expected_sum = (number_of_terms+1)/2.0*(progression.first+progression.last)
```

Using formula for the summation of an arithmetic progression: n/2 ( a[0] + a[n] ).

Here dividing by 2.0 is important. Need to keep precision.

```
actual_sum = progression.inject(:+)
```

Checking what was the sum of the given numbers.

```
missing_element = (expected_sum - actual_sum).to_i
```

Difference is of course the missing element. Also converting into an integer to remove trailing .0

i.e. 4.0 => 4

```
puts "Missing element is: #{missing_element}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for

1) Any value of N (given 5 in example)

2) Any Difference between terms (given 2 in example)

3) Difference can be + as well as - (example: 11 5 2 -1 -4)

```
int diff[]= new int[length-1];
for(int i = 0; i<length-1;i++){
    diff[i] = n1[i+1]-n1[i];
    System.out.println(diff[i]);
    if(i!=0){
        if(diff[i]<diff[i-1]){
            if(diff[i]<0)
                System.out.println(n1[i]+diff[i-1]);
            else
                System.out.println(n1[i-1]+diff[i]);
            break;
        }
        if(diff[i]>diff[i-1]){
            if(diff[i]<0)
                System.out.println(n1[i-1]+diff[i]);
            else
                System.out.println(n1[i]+diff[i-1]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

n1 is where you store the number array from String.

Length is how many numbers you are providing.

This is optimized so that if you miss number in between first two numbers then it only loops 3 times no matter how many numbers you have given

Comment: You know that you are code would take O(n) run time.?

Comment: @Varun yes it does, have to come up with log(n) algorithm. This one is just to get job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int findDelta(long *x, int n);

int main(){
    int n;
        fscanf(stdin,"%d",&n); 
        long *x= (long*) calloc(n,sizeof(long));
    long k;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%ld",&k);
        x[i]=k;
    }

    int delta=findDelta(x,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if (x[i+1]-x[i] != delta)
            printf("%ld\n",x[i]+delta);
    }
    free(x);    
    return 0;
}

int findDelta(long *x, int n){
    long delta1,delta2;
    delta1=x[1]-x[0];
    int d1Count=0;
    int d2Count=0;

    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++){
        delta2=x[i+1]-x[i];
        if(delta2==delta1)
          d1Count++;
        else
          d2Count++;
    }
    if (d1Count > d2Count)
        return (delta1);
    else
        return (delta2);
}
```

Comment: Basic point is to find the delta of the progression. It's either the very first delta or it isn't.